# Clion Remote - Is it possible to create a Remote Toolchain and apply it to a Project?

Tags: cmake, clion

I am following the Clion Blog article: [Stay Local, let your IDE do remote work for you](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2018/09/initial-remote-dev-support-clion)
Under the heading, "How to configure a remote project in Clion?" I'm told: first of all go to settings/preferences / Build, Execution, Deployment / Toolchains: Create a new Toolchain

So, I'm guessing the author is suggesting that 'first' I can go to the toolchains dialog and create a 'remote toolchain' with ssh settings and so forth.

However, Clion does not seem to enable access to the Toolchains configuration unless I already have a project.

So is this a problem of my expectations for accurate precision being too high, or is there actually a way to create a toolchain configuration without first creating a project to associate the toolchain configuration with?

Also, after creating a toolchain configuration associated with a project, how can I associate that toolchain with other projects, as other areas of the bloc seem to say is possible?

Thanks,
Stato Machino

Answer (score 1):

> However, Clion does not seem to enable access to the Toolchains configuration unless I already have a project.

Hi Stato. You can configure your toolchain from Welcome screen or on IDE first running without opening any project.

[image]

> Also, after creating a toolchain configuration associated with a project, how can I associate that toolchain with other projects, as other areas of the bloc seem to say is possible?

When you create CMake project or opening existing one CLion creates new profile with `Default` toolchain. Default is just a first toolchain in the list. So simply moving Remote toolchain to the top in *Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolchains* will automatically switch all your project to remote mode.